# How to update password in Visual Studio 2019 - Live Share account?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-liveshare

I'm trying to live share my code in Visual Studio 2019 Preview (Version 16.0.0 Preview 4.2).

At initial time when providing the credential, accidentally I gave wrong password. So it prompting me the warning as below:

[image: invalid credential]

In plaintext:

> Failed to authenticate the user due to invalid credentials

In the warning window, if I click the "Retry" button it again prompt a popup window to select the account as shown below.

[image: select account]

After selecting the account, I didn't see any option to update the password or unlink the existing account.

So is there any option to provide the correct password or unlink the existing account?

Comment: i think it uses some cookie/cache of browser. open your brower(better your default browser) and switch user and come back to vs and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today when I have updated the Live Share version to `0.3.1403.0`, the authenticate issue was automatically resolved.

Seems there was an issue with the previous version `0.3.1402.1`. With the recent version I can able to live share my screen to others.

> [image: Live Share]